# message from background thread android

Tags: android, multithreading, background, message

why in this code, not working? control of the if statement is bypassed

```
@Override  
public void run() {   

  try {        

      Log.d("UDP", "S: Connecting..."); 

      // CREO ED INIZIALIZZO IL SOCKET UDP 
      DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(null);
      socket.setReuseAddress(true);
      socket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(SERVERIP, SERVERPORT));
      //DEFINISCO LA GRANDEZZA DEL BUFFER IN RICEZIONE

      byte[] buf = new byte[64];  
     //CREO ED INIZIALIZZO IL PACCHETTO

      DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);  
      Log.d("UDP", "S: Ricezione...");  
      IL SERVER SI METTE IN "RICEZIONE" DEL PACCHETTO 

      socket.receive(packet);  

      Log.d("UDP", "S: Ricevuto: " + new String(buf, 0, packet.getLength()) + "'");  
      Log.d("UDP", "S: Ok.");  

      String risultato= new String(buf, 0, packet.getLength());
      System.err.println(risultato);



      if(risultato=="COMANDO RICEVUTO CORRETTAMENTE"){
          // Showing Alert Message
          alertDialog.show();
          System.err.println("ALERT DIALOG");
      }


 } catch (Exception e) {  
      Log.e("UDP", "S: Error", e);  
 } 
 }
```

Comment: Translate the comment in English. String content need equals to be compared. Using == will compare strings references

Comment: becausse you can't access the UI from a non UI thread. Read about AsyncTask and maybe this one too - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Agreed with @mihail. It's better use AsyncTask which is comfortable.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if(risultato=="COMANDO RICEVUTO CORRETTAMENTE"){
          // Showing Alert Message
          alertDialog.show();
          System.err.println("ALERT DIALOG");
 }
```

with

```
 if(risultato.equalsIgnoreCase("COMANDO RICEVUTO CORRETTAMENTE")){
          // Showing Alert Message
          alertDialog.show();
          System.err.println("ALERT DIALOG");
 }
```

in Java `==` for Strings object compares the String's reference not theirs content

Answer (score 0):

It is good practise to create `final String CONSTANT_NAME` on the top of code to make it more representable. 
Also, please read this tutorial to learn some programming patterns:

http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/03/27/incorporating-socket-programming-into-your-applications/